# The end of a cave

Tags: word-request

> The end of a cave.

The entrance of a cave will end to a part. what is this called?

Should I just say an 'end'? or is there any specific term?

Comment: You can say "the end of cave or the cave end".

Answer (score 2):

The "end of a cave" could have two interpretations (depending on whether you are going in, or going out).  I'll list both.

1. The rock wall stopping you going any further in. (From the perspective of walking into the cave)

   You'd call this the **back of the cave**
2. The point at which you exit the cave. (From the perspective of being inside it)

   You'd simply refer to this as the **entrance,** the **exit**  or **mouth of the
   cave**.

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of friends whose hobby is potholing.  They always refer to the *Furthest Reaches* of a cave.

If you google the phrase [*Furthest Reaches*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=cave+furthest+reaches) you get a number of caving websites that use it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any particular caving terminology for the end of the cave, but you could call it the ***terminus*** of the cave.

> *terminus* - a final point in space or time; an end or extremity.